# Show post comments with relationship - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I am new to Laravel and I and trying to create a relationship bewteen my posts and post comments.

I want to show all comments on a post with the same post_id as the posts id.
I think it should look something like this. But I can not get it to work. Any suggestions ?

In the App\BlogComments.php

```
   public function posts(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
   }
```

In the App\Post.php

```
public function BlogComments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\BlogComments');
}
```

In the BlogCommentsController:

```
   public function getComment($id)
    {   
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return $blogcomments->with('posts', $post->blogcomments);
    }
```

In the posts/show.blade.php

```
 @foreach($blogcomments as $blogcomment) 
       {{$blogcomment->comment}}
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In controller use this

```
public function getComment($id)
{   
    $post = Post::with('blogcomments')->find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->with('blogcomments', $post->blogcomments);
}
```

Or if only need blogComments that case

```
public function getComment($id)
{   
    $blogcomments = BlogComments::where('post_id', $id)->get;
    return view('posts.show')->with('blogcomments', $blogcomment);
}
```

Or you can do it this way

```
public function getComment($id)
{   
    $post = Post::with('blogcomments')->find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($post->blogcomments as $blogcomment) 
    {{$blogcomment->comment}}
@endforeach
```

Edit: for comment issue

In BlogComments model define

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And usage

```
$post = Post::with('blogcomments.user')->find($id);
```

Comment: But I want to return the comments in the posts/show.blade.php and the post show blade is returne by the PostController:

  public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
    }

So I can I return it in a view called blogcomments and get it into the post.show view ?
I would rather create it in a array, that I can show in a foreach

Comment: Perfect @Davit just what I needed

Comment: I actually have an addiitonal question @Davit - How can I also add an extra relation to the user who has create the post. So I both bring in the comment and user relation. The user is in the App\User.php and Controllers\UserController.php and got the relationship in the table "tb_blog_comments by the field "user_id"

Comment: Thank you @Davit. But I still can not echo the users name and picture when I try in the foreach with {{$blogcomment->name}} and I dont get any error as well

Comment: `{{$blogcomment->user->name ?? ''}}` for php >= 7, and for php <= 5.6 `{{! empty($blogcomment->user->name) ? $blogcomment->user->name :  ''}}`

Comment: it is working. Amazing job. I could use you as mentor to get introduced to Laravel haha. Thanks again

Comment: if I can bother you once again. Each post is also connected to a category. I have tried to use same method as above, with the relationships and bringing it into the view but without luck. I get this error: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object". In the posts table the is a collum called cat_id and then i have the table tb_blog_categories with collum id that match the cat_id.@Davit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189976/discussion-between-htobiassen-and-davit).